# is the sequence $\Big(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Big)^{(-1)^nn}$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

is this sequence : $\Big(1+\Big(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Big)\Big)^{n(-1)^n}$  divergent ?
I notice that when $n$ is even it converges to $e$ and when $n$ is odd is converges to $e$ as well but I've seen somewhere that this sequence is divergent.  how is that ?

Comment: Where did you see that it does not converge? If both even subsequences and odd subsequences converge to the same value, then the original sequence does what?

Comment: has to be convergent

Comment: Odd subsequence has the form $$\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{-1}\to \left(e^{-1}\right)^{-1}=e.$$

Comment: Please consider to modify the title, it's misleading with respect to the asked question.

Comment: If you could show $|a_n-e| \lt \frac{2}{n}$ for integer $n \gt 1$, would that persuade you the sequence converged to $e$?  Could you show this or something similar for the two subsequences?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to show that if $a_{2n}\to a$ and $a_{2n-1}\to a$ then $a_n\to a$. This is an easy observation.